# All the rows are invisible in the grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have written a method like

```
     private void AvoidDuplicate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < grdView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtoldvalue = grdView.Rows[i].FindControl("txtLicenseNumber") as TextBox;
            string oldvalue = txtoldvalue.Text.ToString();

            for (int j = 0; j < grdView.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                TextBox txtnewvalue = grdView.Rows[j].FindControl("txtLicenseNumber") as TextBox;
                string newvalue = txtnewvalue.Text.ToString();
                if (oldvalue == newvalue)
                {
                    grdView.Rows[j].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This function is called when page is loaded. The issue is that it is making all the rows in the gridview invisible. I want to check only if there are textbox with the same values only one of rows should become invisible. Please help

Comment: Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

try using a dictionary. to get all unique values then check if you dictionary contains the value if not make it invisible

```
private void AvoidDuplicate()
{
  Dictionary<string,string> checkdictionary=new Dictionary<string,string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < grdView.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBox txtnewvalue = grdView.Rows[i].FindControl("txtLicenseNumber") as TextBox;
            string newvalue = txtnewvalue.Text.ToString();
        if(!checkdictionary.ContainsKey(newvalue))
        {
             checkdictionary[newvalue]="something";
        }
        else
        {
          grdView.Rows[i].Visible = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I want to compare the values already existing in the grid view's textboxes... Please help me

Comment: thats what this is doing. the dictionary will hold all unique values that are in you text boxes. If its a unique value it is added to the dictionary else it means this value was already encountered so make the row visibility false

Comment: Can u please show how will i assign values to the dictionary... pleasw

Comment: checkdictionary[newvalue]="something"; this baiscally puts the newvalue as key for the dictionary. and the value doesnt matter.the key is important. just implement this code which i have posted abve and check

Comment: why was this answer downvoted? its a perfectly legal answer to the askers question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124646/discussion-between-mysterio11-and-nida).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 private void AvoidDuplicate()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < grdView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox txtoldvalue = grdView.Rows[i].FindControl("txtLicenseNumber") as TextBox;
                string oldvalue = txtoldvalue.Text.ToString();

                for (int j = 0; j < grdView.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                   if( j == i)
                     continue;
TextBox txtnewvalue = grdView.Rows[j].FindControl("txtLicenseNumber") as TextBox;
                    string newvalue = txtnewvalue.Text.ToString();
                    if (oldvalue == newvalue)
                    {
                        grdView.Rows[j].Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Easier way would be, use **DataView**

```
    //populate your datatable dt. List your columns in ToTable method that you want to include in uniqueness of row.

    dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "LicenseNumber");
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: sorry the above code in which loop is implemented is not working... please help me!!!